# How to manipulate content from the Polymer Element

Tags: polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

I am creating a **top bar polymer element** which will be **responsive**.

```
        <top-menu query="max-width: 500px">
            <a href="#">What ToDo</a>
            <a href="#">Where ToDo</a>
            <a href="#">Add ToDo</a>
        </top-menu>
```

I want to add extra style to the menu item.

```
<polymer-element name="top-menu" attributes="query" noscript>
<template>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="top-menu.css">

        <template if="{{smallScreen}}">
            <core-menu-button icon="menu"
                              inlineMenu halign="left" valign="bottom">
                <content></content>
            </core-menu-button>
        </template>
        <!-- ...otherwise display them in the toolbar -->
        <div id="topMenuItem"><content></content></div>

    <core-media-query
            query="{{query}}"
            queryMatches="{{smallScreen}}">
    </core-media-query>

</template>
<script>
    Polymer('top-menu', {
        attached: function() {
            debugger;
            var menus = this.$.topMenuItem.firstChild;

            menus.forEach(function(menu){
                var shadow = menu.createShadowRoot();
                shadow.innerHTML = '<paper-button label="flat button"><content></content></paper-button>';
            })
        }
    });
</script>
```

The Issue I  am facing I can not find any proper **Element lifecycle methods** where I can get the content of . If I search for **this.$.topMenuItem.firstChild** I only find  it is alwasy blank for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `domReady` handler will fire once the DOM has been processed and is ready for you to interact with it.

Note that to get the content of a `<content>` element one must call [`.getDistributedNodes()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/#the-content-element) on it.